# How to capture Multiple response for a same request in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am initiating the request from Jmeter using HTTP Request Sampler. In the body data i am sending the request and the application server sends back two different responses for the same request. After receiving the first response, Jmeter will close the request and in my scenario i need to capture the second response also. Kindy share your ideas on this.

Regards,
Chandru

Answer (score 0):

Which protocol? In case of [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) this is exactly how it supposed to work: one request -> one response, you can [keep the underlying TCP connection alive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Keep-Alive) so JMeter would re-use the connection for sending the next request, but [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler won't expect any additional responses.

In case of [Server Side Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) you will need to do some scripting in order to handle the situation like it's described in [How to Load Test SSE Services with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-load-test-sse-services-with-jmeter) article

In case of [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) take a look at [Read continuation frames.jmx example test plan](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/samples/Read%20continuation%20frames.jmx)